# Elixir/Erlang - Nanosleep

Tags: erlang, elixir, sleep, nano

Is there an nanosleep for Elixir/Erlang out there?
Erlangs `timer.sleep` does "only" take milliseconds and Im looking for a shorter sleep than that.

Comment: According to http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-March/025677.html, there wasn't anything like this at least in 2007. The solution proposed there was to "busy wait", i.e. keep checking the time in a loop until the duration you want to sleep for has passed. The author of the post finally went with the busy wait solution.

Comment: Approximately how many nanoseconds do you want to sleep for? If it's tiny, busy waiting might actually be good enough.

Comment: Something to consider: how exact does the sleep duration need to be? I guess Erlang's preemptive scheduler might put a spoke in your wheel here. If you're unlucky the scheduler might interrupt the process in the middle of your busy wait loop and you'd end up sleeping much longer than you wanted. Depending on your use case it might not be a problem though.

Comment: What @PatrickOscity said - Erlang's soft realtime architecture probably only guarantees some modicum of precision on millisecond level when trying to time stuff. We could maybe help more if you state your use case - unless you're doing very low level (device driver) work, which you should maybe consider doing in C to begin with, sleeping is frowned upon in the Erlang world from what I read.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in doing something like this:

```
defmodule TimeCheck do
  def time_ok(time) do
    if :erlang.system_time - time < 10000 do
      TimeCheck.time_ok(time)
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```